# WSL MySQL fails to stop - requires kill -9 pid to stop it

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, anaconda

I am having trouble getting MySQL to stop running without having to kill it using the process id. This can become a problem, especially if I update or upgrade my packages. MySQL is always a bit finicky on my computer, so I do have to start and stop MySQL to log in successfully. I know a couple people who have the same issue with WSL. In my case, for some reason,

`sudo service mysql stop`

keeps returning as [fail]. This happens from the moment after I start MySQL, before I have done anything for my projects. Because of this, I do not believe that there is a problem with a running query.

Currently, I use the following code to stop MySQL if there is something requiring MySQL to be stopped:

`ps aux | grep mysql | grep -v grep`

and then kill it using the process id using

`sudo kill -9 <insert pid here>`

sudo kill  alone does not work.

I was wondering if there was a way to fix this permanently so that sudo service mysql stop will work as it is supposed to. I have tried removing and reinstalling mysql in my anaconda environment multiple times, but I keep running into the same issue.

My WSL version is version 0.2.1, and I use Ubuntu 20.04.

I installed mysql using the following code as per the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database#install-mysql):

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

This is the content of the error.log in /var/log/mysql:

```
2022-08-02T22:32:48.424160Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) initializing of server in progress as process 3932
2022-08-02T22:32:48.448955Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-02T22:32:49.492155Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-08-02T22:32:52.150238Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option. 
2022-08-02T22:32:54.741914Z 6 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2).
2022-08-02T22:32:59.154929Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 3986
2022-08-02T22:32:59.188694Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-02T22:32:59.705173Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. How exactly did you install `mysql`? Is there any information in files in `/var/log/mysql/`? If there is a non-empty `error.log`, please copy&paste the contents (or a relevant part of it) and format it as a code block. (Use separate lines for the 3 backticks.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have added in that information.